# filter leads dashlet

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to filter out all leads that have been converted in the dashlet. so I pretty much want to add a custom where condition to show all leads except converted. what and where would I add this code in the dashlet folder of leads.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of each dashlet, by clicking the small edit icon on the dashlet. For the leads dashlet you can define which status values are included.([See SugarCRM documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-Application_Guides-Sugar_Community_Edition_Application_Guide_6.2.0GA-User_Interface.html#1140966)). If you want to change the existing sugarCRM dashlets, which shouldn't be necessary in this case, it is described [here](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0.html#9000223).